# Xpath checkbox locators

Tags: java, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

I'm using Selenium for my autotests but got stack with XPATH.

I need to delete user and groups from address book but I do not understand which locator i need to use
I was trying using different Xpaths, but maybe you can tell me what to read because now I' totally lost.

HTML of the addressbook:

[image: Here is addressbook]

What I've tried

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//form[@lastname='Anna']/input")).click();
```

and

```
//table[@id='maintable']/tbody/tr[12]/td[2]
```

Comment: Please update the question with text based HTML to received effective solution form other contributor.

Answer (score 0):

To `click()` on the [checkbox](/questions/tagged/checkbox) with for user **Anna** you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- `cssSelector`:

  ```
  driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("input[title*='Anna'][alt*='Anna'][type='checkbox']")).click();
  ```
- `xpath`:

  ```
  driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[contains(@title, 'Anna') and contains(@alt, 'Anna')][@type='checkbox']")).click();
  ```

---

Ideally to `click()` on the element you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48989049/selenium-how-selenium-identifies-elements-visible-or-not-is-is-possible-that-i/48990165#48990165) for the `elementToBeClickable()` and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- `cssSelector`:

  ```
  new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.cssSelector("input[title*='Anna'][alt*='Anna'][type='checkbox']"))).click();
  ```
- `xpath`:

  ```
  new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//input[contains(@title, 'Anna') and contains(@alt, 'Anna')][@type='checkbox']"))).click();
  ```

Answer (score -1):

Your XPath fetch first `input` child of `form` node which is hidden. Try more specific selector

```
"//input[@title='Select (testuser Anna)']"
```